# My server request needs to be converted from Http to Https

Tags: javascript

Actually my request in mobile application will hit the server url(Http) which is not ssl secured. so, from the mbl application i would like to hit my server url in a secured way.. I mean with the use of SSL Protocols like https. How do i convert that from http to https..?

Comment: Maybe you should describe you problem better. It seems a case where you would just use "https://" instead of "http://" has you use now.

Answer (score 0):

On the js-side, you will have to remove any hard-code http prefixes to https. As for your server, you will need to buy an ssl certificate and enable ssl running on port 443.
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/65007

Comment: My application is like to perform some HR related functions. when the user hits apply leave button at the back end it validates against  employer credentials. If everything is fine  then code is written like to hit apache server( url is mentioned application code  in Http). so every request from  my application to the server should be in secure way. We should convert that  from Http to Https. I know the process everything in case of web application to server like installing the certs in server. But how i do that in case of mobile application..?